# Vue template - Add classname dynamically when id of item in list equals variable

Tags: vue.js

I have a big svg map that needs to have certain one part highlighted based on user input.

The svg is essentially a single file component.

Template:

```html
<template>
svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 350 600 450">
        <g>
<path id="X" class="class1" d="4,522.87L164.95,523.31L166.15,524.54L167.29,524.57L169.47,525.42L170.72,525.22L172.59,523.7........" />
<path id="Y" class="class1" d="4,522.87L164.95,523.31L166.15,524.54L167.29,524.57L169.47,525.42L170.72,525.22L172.59,523.7........"/>
<path id="Z" class="class1" d="4,522.87L164.95,523.31L166.15,524.54L167.29,524.57L169.47,525.42L170.72,525.22L172.59,523.7........"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</template>
```

Script:

```
 module.exports = {
        name: 'map',
        props:['userSelect'],
        methods: {
          checkProp: function() {
            console.log(userSelect) 
//prop works as expected
          }
        }
```

What I need is when the id matches the userSelect, I should add another class called "class2" to the existing one "class1".
Anyone has an idea?

Comment: you can add logic to your classes like this:

`<div v-bind:class="[sender_id === userId ? msg-from-me : msg-from-them]">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [v-bind:](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand) or the [shorthand](https://v1.vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand) `:`

example :

```
<template>
svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 350 600 450">
        <g>
<path id="X" :class="setClass('X')" d="4,522.87L164.95,523.31L166.15,524.54L167.29,524.57L169.47,525.42L170.72,525.22L172.59,523.7........" />
<path id="Y" :class="setClass('Y')" d="4,522.87L164.95,523.31L166.15,524.54L167.29,524.57L169.47,525.42L170.72,525.22L172.59,523.7........"/>
<path id="Z" :class="setClass('Z')" d="4,522.87L164.95,523.31L166.15,524.54L167.29,524.57L169.47,525.42L170.72,525.22L172.59,523.7........"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</template>
```

```
 module.exports = {
        name: 'map',
        props:['userSelect'],
        methods: {
          setClass (id) {
            return id === userSelect ? 'class1 class2' : 'class1'
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a component and use a computed property so that it the value is cached:

**MyPath Component**

```
<template>
  <path v-bind="$attrs" :class="pathClass"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['userSelect'],
  computed() {
    pathClass() {
      return this.$el.id === this.userSelect;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Then the map template becomes:

```
<template>
svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 350 600 450">
        <g>
<my-path id="X" :user-select="userSelect" class="class1" d="4,522.87L164.95,523.31L166.15,524.54L167.29,524.57L169.47,525.42L170.72,525.22L172.59,523.7........" />
<my-path id="Y" :user-select="userSelect" class="class1" d="4,522.87L164.95,523.31L166.15,524.54L167.29,524.57L169.47,525.42L170.72,525.22L172.59,523.7........"/>
<my-path id="Z" :user-select="userSelect" class="class1" d="4,522.87L164.95,523.31L166.15,524.54L167.29,524.57L169.47,525.42L170.72,525.22L172.59,523.7........"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
</template>
```